# WordPress Shortcode show database row

Tags: shortcode, database

Good day,

I was wondering if can do a shortcode that gets all the fields in a row stored in a database, with the difference that I do not want to do many shortcodes for the speed of the site.

The row of the database with separate fields, as you will see in the image below.

[image: Database fields]

Or if there is another way to do it and it is better, you're welcome.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by “like an array or something like that”?

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong, I've been thinking many things with this problem

Answer (score 1):

I’m not entirely sure if that’s what you wanted, but... Here’s the code that will register a shortcode, which will get given row and output all the fields of it:

```
function shortcode_db_row_cb( $atts ) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => false,
    ), $atts, 'db_row' );

    global $wpdb;
    $row = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( "select * from {$wpdb->prefix}TABLE_NAME where id = %d", $atts['id'] ), ARRAY_A );
    $res = '';

    if ( $row ) {
        $res = '<table>';
        $res .= '<tr>';
        foreach ( $row as $k => $v ) $res .= '<th>' . esc_html($k) . '</th>';
        $res .= '</tr>';
        $res .= '<tr>';
        foreach ( $row as $k => $v ) $res .= '<to>' . esc_html($v) . '</td>';
        $res .= '</tr>';
        $res .= '</table>';
        return $res;
    }

    return 'no such row';
}
add_shortcode( 'db_row', 'shortcode_db_row_cb' );
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I request data from the row separately? Or is it necessary to create a new shortcode?

Comment: Sorry, but I can’t get what do you mean by that? Do you want to get only some of fields from that row? Do you want to get different rows?

Comment: The first one, only some of fields from that row. Use one shortcode to get the id, another for name.. and so on. Hopefully only with just 1 shortcode to not slow down the site

Comment: Yes, you can [pass parameters to shortcodes](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/shortcodes/shortcodes-with-parameters/). I don't think a few shortcodes will make any difference to the speed of your site though.

Comment: Registering more shortcodes won’t affect the speed of site significantly... And yes, you can pass more params in there - here we pass only the ID, but you can pass field name also.

Comment: For example if I want to get 3 data from that row, I will have to make 3 times the connection to the database? Each query per shortcode?